# Multiple IMPORTHTML requests in a custom array, or in separate cells - same speed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, importhtml

I have a spreadsheet with 62 `IMPORTHTML` requests.  Does it make any difference in speed if I put all of these inside a custom array rather than having them in individual cells?

Comment: Neither of them ever finish loading because of the large number of requests.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the maximum number of **`IMPORTHTML()`** formulas per spreadsheet is **50** and if those **50** are in an array or separately, the difference is none

> [image: 1]

Comment: Is it possible to circumvent this by placing 30 of the IMPORTHTML calls in one spreadsheet, 30 in another spreadsheet, and then in a final spreadsheet use IMPORTRANGE to merge the resultant tables?

Comment: @TylerGubala yeah, it should be doable